# What's up with this c++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm just learning to code using MVS, watching "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0WuJGhFhlU"

Here's the code...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main();
{
    //Get seed colour
    string seedColour = ""; //The empty "" is what "seedColor" will be chaned to after cin.
    cout << "Enter Seed Colour (Red/Blue?) \n";
    cin >> seedColour; //The user will iunput the seed's colour, which will change the empty "" and we now have (eg) "string seedColour = "red""

    //Get Temp
    int temp = 0;
        cout << "Enter the Temp \n";
    cin >> temp;

    //Get Soil Moisture
    string soilMoisture = "";
    cout >> "Is the soil Wet or dry? \n";
    cin >> soilMoisture;

        //if red seed
    if (seedColour == "red")
    {
        //if temp >= 75
        if (temp >= 75)
        {

            //if soil is wet
            if (soilMoisture == "wet")
            {
                //Output Sunflower
                cout << "SUNFLOWER LAR.\n";
            }
            //if soil dry
            if (soilMoisture == "dry")
            {
                //Dandelion
                cout << "Dandelion.\n";
            }

            //Otherwwise (temp <75)
            else
            {
                //Mushroom
                cout << "Mushroom";

            }
        }
    }

    //if blue
    if (seedColour == "blue")
    {
        //temp between 60 n 70
        if (temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)
        {
            //wet soil
            if (soilMoisture == "wet")
            {
                //Dandilion
                cout << "Dandilion \n";
            }

            //dry soil
            if (soilMoisture == "dry")
            {
                //Sunflower
                cout << "Sunflower";

            }
        }


        //Otherwise
        else
        {
            //mushroom
            cout << "Mushroom";
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

I get 3 "expected a declaration errors.

One on the original { after "int main"

One on the "if" of "if (seedColour == "red")

One on the closing } after "cout << "Mushroom";"

I'm also getting a " '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) "

How come I'm getting these errors?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you include `<string>`, `<string.h>` and `<cstring>` here? You should actually only need `<string>` in this case. `<cstring>` is for functions dealing with C like strings i.e. `char *` only. `<string.h>` existed before C++ was standardized in 1998 and is purely legacy nowadays and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main();
```

remove the semicolon after main.

And as songyuanyao pointed out:

```
cout >> "Is the soil Wet or dry? \n";
```

should be

```
cout << "Is the soil Wet or dry? \n";
```

Comment: @JackJones Try `cout << ...`

Comment: Thanks! It's not working as expected but whatever. Let's just say I did it. Nice one again bud!

Comment: @JackJones it's `cout <<` and `cin >>`, an easy way to remember is with `cout` you want it to go **FROM** the variable to cout, with `cin` you want it to go from cin **TO** the variable

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind